# How to unit test this function using TDD?

Tags: javascript, tdd, jestjs

When the function is inside class and unit test the function calculate it gives me  some error. How to test calculate function using TDD?. Please help me.

1.calculation.js

```
export default class calculation {
    static  calculate(a, b) {
        var sum1 = this.addition(a, b);
        var sub1 = this.subtract(a, b);
        return {
             sum1: sum1, 
             sub1: sub1
        };
    }
    static addition (a, b) {
        var sum = a + b;
        return sum;
    }
    static subtract (a, b) {
        var sub = a - b;
        return sub;
    }
}
```

2.calculation.test.js

```
const calculate = require('../app/calculation');
describe('calculation', () => {
    let result;
    beforeEach(() => {
        result = calculate.calculate(100, 50);
    });
    it('correct sum of two number is', () => {
        expect(result.sum1).toBe(150);
    });
    it('correct subtract of two number is', () => {
        expect(result.sub1).toBe(50);
    });
```

});

error is ...

● calculation › correct sum of two number is

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'sum1' of undefined

  at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/calculation.test.js:8:14)
  at tryCallTwo (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:45:5)
  at doResolve (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:200:13)
  at new Promise (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:66:3)
  at tryCallOne (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
  at node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:123:15
```

● calculation › correct subtract of two number is

```
TypeError: calculate.calculate is not a function

  at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/calculation.test.js:5:18)
  at tryCallTwo (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:45:5)
  at doResolve (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:200:13)
  at new Promise (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:66:3)
  at tryCallOne (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
  at node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:123:15
```

● calculation › correct subtract of two number is

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'sub1' of undefined

  at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/calculation.test.js:11:14)
  at tryCallTwo (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:45:5)
  at doResolve (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:200:13)
  at new Promise (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:66:3)
  at tryCallOne (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
  at node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:123:15
```

calculation
    ✕ correct sum of two number is (3ms)
    ✕ correct subtract of two number is (1ms)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       2 failed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.818s, estimated 1s
Ran all test suites.
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.

Comment: ● calculation › correct sum of two number is

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'sum' of undefined
      
      at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/calculation.test.js:8:14)
      at tryCallTwo (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:45:5)
      at doResolve (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:200:13)
      at new Promise (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:66:3)
      at tryCallOne (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
      at node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:123:15

  ● calculation › correct subtract of two number is

Comment: run the command  npm test  then it give such error . i will include all file above . @ Nicholas Tower.

Comment: same error  here  after change result.sum1 and result.sub1 . @Nicholas Tower

Comment: Dont put more information into  comments. Always update your question instead. Or can you read what you put down in that first comment?

Comment: Thank you @ GhostCat  for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking the wrong question. 
Test Driven Development is a development process.

You don't test something with TDD, your build something using it.

I recommend this [excellent article on TDD.](https://jrsinclair.com/articles/2016/gentle-introduction-to-javascript-tdd-intro/) I think it will clear things up.